# Groovy Migration for Java Developer

Tags: java, groovy

I've been a Java developer for several years now. Lately there's been quite the buzz over **Groovy**. I checked it out and it looks interesting and all, but I'm not seeing any inherent "wow factor" to it; meaning, I'm not seeing any intrinsic value to begin developing in it.

Now, I'm *positive* that I'm just not seeing the forest through the trees here. So, I ask the SO community at large: how would learning Groovy behoove any Java developer? What features/capabilities/etc. does it do (or do better) than plain ole' Java?

Things in the software world don't take off like wildfire without a reason. I'm sure Groovy has all sorts of nifty little (and big) capabilities that make it a must-know; I'm just not "getting" it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would one use Groovy over Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764416/why-would-one-use-groovy-over-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my opinion, some of the biggest adventages Groovy has over Java are:

- terser code thanks to overloaded operators and simplified property access. Instead of writing

  ```
  if (obj1.getBar().equals(obj2.getBaz())) { 
      obj3.setFoo("equal");
  }
  ```

  you can write

  ```
  if (obj1.bar == obj2.baz) {
      obj3.foo = "equal"
  }
  ```

which I consider much more readable.

- inline notation for Maps and Lists. Instead of

  ```
  Map attributes = new HashMap();
  attributes.put("color", "red");
  attributes.put("width", 1);
  ```

you can write

```
    def attributes = [color: "red", width: 1]
```

- useful extensions to standard libraries. For example, you can read files and webpages like this:

  ```
  def fileContents = new File('readme.txt').text
  def pageContents = new URL('readme.txt').text
  ```
- syntactic sugar for initializing properties - for example,

  ```
  MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
  myObject.setFoo("bar");
  myObject.setBaz(23);
  ```

can be replaced by

```
    def myObject = new MyClass(foo: "bar", baz: 23)
```

- 'safe' dereferencing - `if (str != null) {return str.toUppercase();} else {return null;}` becomes `return str?.toUppercase()`
- Regular Expressions look nicer
- Closures allow you to write code in 'functional' style, and make writing things like event listeners way easier

Comment: In the last code example, could the same code shortening just be done by providing a constructor for MyClass that takes in initializers for the instance variables of the class?

Answer (score 1):

... since no one pitched in so far, I'd suggest looking at the [Grooy mailing list](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Mailing+Lists). Similar questions pop up from time to time regarding Grails as well. Those are great communities of people who at some point or another faced the same type of questions.

Answer (score 1):

You're kinda late to the party. Groovy saw its dawn about 4 years ago when people fed up with Java's ridiculous verboseness were ready to give up performance in the sake of code reduction and Groovy was providing them with exactly that in a very familiar syntax. But now that it's been there for a while it gets dragged by its past as much as every language does and some not best design decisions are there to stay as much as I'm pretty sure are its performance issues. This basically was the reason of emergence of Groovy++, the whole existance of which suggests that there are some problems with its predecessor. And in fact Groovy++ addresses a lot of issues of its predecessor, but it also has its own problems: the main one being that it's basically driven only by the devotion of a one man - Alex Tkachman that is, - and no funding, so you should see all the risks involved.

Nowadays that more and more strong rivals appear (Kotlin, Ceylon) it becomes obvious to me that Groovy has already passed even its zenith - even its core team is trembling (you should see their discussions on Grumpy mode). This was the reason for me to start gradually leaving this technology in preference to Scala and to look forward to forthcoming Kotlin which both are great projects but take some effort for a "Java mind" to switch to, but are definitely worth it.

**Updates due to hypercritical response**:

1. Design mistakes:

   - Restricting syntax for Java paste-in compatibility, while a seemingly neat feature in practice turned out to be not used at all, 'cuz migrating Java code to Groovy is generally a bad idea for the same performance reasons. But this resulted in inheritance of some Java's ridiculousness like not being able to define a variable of the name used in the outer context
   - While keeping some of Java's bad practices they got rid of some of its good features too, like code blocks demarked with curly braces in preference to closures. The issue solved much neater in Scala
   - Dynamic typing was mainly chosen because decent type inferring was hard to realize - that was basically the reason for Groovy's creator to later state that [he would have never bothered creating it if he knew about Scala back then](http://macstrac.blogspot.com/2009/04/scala-as-long-term-replacement-for.html).
2. Googling for "groovy performance" will give you enough results. Here is one: http://stronglytypedblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/java-vs-scala-vs-groovy-vs-groovy.html
3. I never stated that Groovy++ is the same project as core Groovy.

I would like you to know that I once was a huge fan of Groovy and was developing in it exclusively for 2 straight years. Moving on to a new language was a very hard step for me to take. But since I know Groovy's every corner, I know its core team and its tendencies you should understand that I know what I'm doing when I'm recommending not to consider Groovy as an alternative to Java.

Comment: There are a lot of vague unsupported assertions in this answer. Can we have some examples of these "not best design decisions" or performance issues. Also, you say that Groovy++ is the successor to Groovy, this is just not true. They are two separate projects.

Comment: They're only two different projects because the Codehaus custodians of Groovy don't want to bundle code they don't directly control into the Groovy 1.x distros. Both Groovy 1.x and ++ use the same grammar and parser, with Groovy++ an AST-level plugin into the Groovy distro. Just drop the Groovy++ jar into the Groovy 1.x classpath, annotate your project with @Typed, and you've suddenly got faster performance and type inference in your Groovy program. The Grumpy is a Codehaus "just enough" clone of Groovy++ to dissuade programmers from using Groovy++.

Comment: I thought that something like that was the reason. Now I feel sorry for Alex. All the time he spent becomes worthless because of political decisions. And instead of evolving Groovy the core team goes into reinventing the bycicle. IMO the only way they could have saved Groovy was to make it static only in the version 2.0, since it wouldn't be backward compatible anyway. What's happening now is just sad: chaos and chaotic projects have no future.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another, since I don't see it explicitly mentioned.

For me, while terseness is nice on its own, it isn't the main point.

Whatever code you write, Java will always look like Java, and it will never read like the problem you're solving--it will read like Java, solving your problem.

I want the reverse: I want my code to read like the problem I'm solving, written in [insert language here].

Groovy is more expressive, more malleable than Java. It can look like what I'm trying to do. Canonical examples of this include internal DSLs. One I've used frequently is [easyb](http://www.easyb.org/storyexmpls.html), which is just Groovy code, but sounds like what I'm doing when I read it out loud. There are a bunch more examples, but easyb is an easy sell.

Also not mentioned are the AST transformations allowing cool compile-time tricks. You can play similar games in Java with things like AspectJ, but it's not as "baked in". Things like @Delegate, @Singleton, etc. are just plain handy.

For me, a language needs to be malleable, deformable, flexible: Java is not. Java has an impoverished model of abstraction making it frustrating to work with--the amount of extra work, writ both small and large throughout the language, is mind-boggling at times.